# In Python I have embedded SQL code with 2 sets of between dates. How to loop the python code to run multiple sets of between dates

Tags: python, sql, arrays, date, vector

I am new to this so sorry if my question is odd or confusing. In python I have an embedded SQL query that has 2 between dates for data. I have several dates I want to loop this code through each 'between date sets' I have for the entire month. I feel like I am missing a package that would help with this and I have not found a tutorial to follow something like this. 
Say for example sake. 

`List of between dates
2020-02-01 AND 2020-02-05,
2020-02-02 AND 2020-02-06,
2020-02-03 AND 2020-02-07,
... all the way to ...
2020-02-28 AND 2020-03-04`

Where I am at so far is this and I can't figure out how to setup an array for this.

```
import psybopg2
import getpass
import pandas

con = psybopg2.connect(host="blah",database="blah",user=getpass.getpass

cur.execute("""

SELECT
Address
,Create_Data
,Event_Date

FROM
table.a

WHERE
Create_Date between '2020-03-20' AND '2020-03-25' --(want to insert set of dates from the list
AND 
Event_Date between '2020-03-20' AND '2020-03-25' --(want to insert the same between date used above

""")

output = cur.fetchall ()

data = pd.DataFrame(output)

cur.close()
con.close()`
```

Comment: What database you want to connect to ? There are numerous python packages available for various database types.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give an example of what you would like to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` and `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = "2020-02-01"
stop_date = "2020-02-28"

start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
stop = datetime.strptime(stop_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

from datetime import timedelta
while start < stop:
    first_date = start #first date for between
    second_date = start + timedelta(days=4) #second date for between
    #Use the above in sql query
    start = start + timedelta(days=1)  # increase day one by one
```